# Turnoff layer not selected in form element Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm super stuck, pulling my hair out. I have graduated symbol map in leaflet of wildlife camera rates of detection. I have a form element that selects all species, bobcats, coyotes o grey foxes. All species is default map state and displays fine. When I select Bobcat, the 2nd dropdown option the color defined in my if/else statement is change based on the other colors underneath the bobcat selection. I know this because if I comment out the coyote and fox portion of the code the bobcat displays correctly. I'm sure it's something small but I can't figure it out. Below is the code specifically for the form element. Thanks in advance for your help.

````
  omnivore.csv('Data/DetectionRates_BCGF_V7.csv')
    .on('ready', function (e) {
      // access geoJson here
      drawMap(e.target.toGeoJSON());
      drawLegend(e.target.toGeoJSON());
      // console.log(e.target.toGeoJSON()) 
      // console.log(e.target)
      // all data loaded into the layer
    })
    .on('error', function (e) {
      // if the error can't be parsed or loaded over AJAX
      console.log(e.error[0].message);
    })

  function drawMap(data) {
    // console.log(data)
    const options = {
      pointToLayer: function (feature, ll) {
        // Letters instead of numbers
        return L.circleMarker(ll, {

          weight: 2,
          fillOpacity: 0,
          opacity: 1,


        });
      }

    }

    // create 4 separate layers
    const bobcatLayer = L.geoJson(data, options)
    coyoteLayer = L.geoJson(data, options)
    foxLayer = L.geoJson(data, options)
    interactiveLayer = L.geoJson(data, options).addTo(map);


    // fit the bounds to one of the layers
    map.fitBounds(interactiveLayer.getBounds());


    interactiveLayer.setStyle({
      weight: 2,
      color: '#222'


    });

    // adjust zoom level
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - .4);

    // set initial circle size in map
    resizeCircles(interactiveLayer, 9, species)

    // call sequenceUI function
    sequenceUI(interactiveLayer)
    dropDownUI(interactiveLayer)


  } // end drawMap

  function calcRadius(val) {
    const radius = Math.sqrt(val / Math.PI);
    return radius * 10; // adjust scale factor
  }
  // resize circles based on detection rates using radius scaling
  function resizeCircles(interactiveLayer, monthYear, species) {

    if (species == "all") {
      interactiveLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {

        layer.setStyle({
         color: '#173560'

        })

        const props = layer.feature.properties
        const relativeDetRate = Number(props['b' + monthYear]) + Number(props['c' + monthYear]) + Number(props['f' + monthYear])
        const radius = calcRadius(relativeDetRate);
        if (radius == 0) {
          layer.setStyle({
            color: '#555',
            radius: 0.5
          })
        } else {
          layer.setRadius(radius);
        }

      });
    } else {

      interactiveLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {

        layer.setStyle({
          color: '#333'

        })

        const props = layer.feature.properties
        const relativeDetRate = Number(props[species + monthYear])
        const radius = calcRadius(relativeDetRate);
        const color = function (species) {
          if (species == 'b') {
            return '#BB952F' 
          } else {
            return '#333'
          }
        }

        // console.log(color(species), species)
        if (radius == 0) {
          layer.setStyle({
            color: '#555',
            radius: 0.5
          })
        } else {
          layer.setRadius(radius)
          layer.setStyle({
          color: color(species)
          })

        }

      });

      interactiveLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {

        layer.setStyle({
          color: '#A21E36'

        })

        const props = layer.feature.properties
        const relativeDetRate = Number(props[species + monthYear])
        const radius = calcRadius(relativeDetRate);
        const color = function (species) {
          if (species == 'c') {
            return '#A21E36' 
          } else {
            return '#333'
          }
        }
        // console.log(color(species), species)
        if (radius == 0) {
          layer.setStyle({
            color: '#555',
            radius: 0.5
          })
        } else {
          layer.setRadius(radius)
          layer.setStyle({
          color: color(species)
          })

        }

      });

      interactiveLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {

        layer.setStyle({
          color: '#A21E36'

        })

        const props = layer.feature.properties
        const relativeDetRate = Number(props[species + monthYear])
        const radius = calcRadius(relativeDetRate);
        const color = function (species) {
          if (species == 'f') {
            return '#3A4B56' 
          } else {
            return '#333'
          }
        }
        // console.log(color(species), species)
        if (radius == 0) {
          layer.setStyle({
            color: '#555',
            radius: 0.5
          })
        } else {
          layer.setRadius(radius)
          layer.setStyle({
          color: color(species)
          })

        }

      });


     }
    retrieveInfo(interactiveLayer, monthYear)
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

if 'use-strict' is being enforced an error might be because you don't have the variable properly declared.

try

```
const coyoteLayer = L.geoJson(data, options)
const foxLayer = L.geoJson(data, options)
const interactiveLayer = L.geoJson(data, options).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks @beskgar - use-strict is not being enforced.